# How to include private methods in rubydoc.info documentation

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I published a gem to RubyGems and it built the documentation for me at http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/step_sequencer/1.0.7. I noticed that it didn't include the private methods which is not ideal from my point of view. I tried switching them all to protected but they still did not show up. Only when I changed them to public did they appear.

Is there a way to configure RubyGems to publish documentation with my own configuration?

For instance methods, I'm using the regular `private` keyword. For class methods I'm using the singleton class like:

```
class Foo
  class << self
    private
    def self.private_class_method
  end
end
```

Neither are showing up even when I add a `.yardopts` file with `--private`

Comment: Why do you want public methods to be included in your documentation? I would argue these should not be used from the outside anyway. So what is the point of adding that methods to a public documentation?

Comment: For the "what you really need to know" overview I have the README. Baiscally, the "show source" button on the public methods won't produce a comprehendable source unless the definitions of the private methods are also there; I know not everyone uses it this way but to each their own. It can also be valuable information to a documentation peruser to know what is happening behind the scenes.

Comment: I suppose in other words I see the README as for the casual gem consumer, and the rubydoc for more advanced people who want to know the ins-and-outs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just ran into the same problem and found the answer as to how to include private and protected methods in your rdocs although it took some digging. There are two ways to do this.

1. To include specific private methods add `#:doc:` to the method definition like this:

   ```
   def my_method #:doc:
   ```
2. To include all private/protected methods add the `--all` option at the end when you generate the docs from the command line. If you have a rake task for updating your docs you can add this line into the block:

   ```
   rdoc.options << "--all"
   ```